# Sending a string from anonymous thread to UI with PostMessage

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, delphi

I am sending a string from an anonymous thread to the UI with `PostMessage` in the following code:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

const
  WM_SETCAPTION = WM_USER;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure WMSetCaption(var msg: TMessage); message WM_SETCAPTION;
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.WMSetCaption(var msg: TMessage);
begin
  Self.Caption := PChar(msg.LParam);
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  System.Classes.TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      PostMessage(Handle, WM_SETCAPTION, 0, LParam(PChar('My new caption')));
    end).Start;
end;

end.
```

This works seemingly well, but could this potentially create memory leaks? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to do this via an extra thread, instead of calling it directly?

Comment: This is only a simplified example from a more complex scenario where a string must be sent from an anonymous thread to the main thread. The central question here is whether doing this with `PostMessage` in the above way could cause any problems whatsoever (e.g. memory leaks).

Comment: Why would you expect there to be a memory leak? The TThread that gets created is `FreeOnTerminate`, so it will Free itself.

Comment: Regarding the string, that could be a problem if you are casting from a regular Delphi string. Delphi strings are reference counted, so by the time your message handler tries to access the string, it may have been deallocated. It might be a good idea to allocate the string yourself with StrNew.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. In the meantime I've found a better solution: I create an object containing the string as a property and pass the pointer to the object as Integer LParam. Then, in the message handler, I use the string and free the object. In this way, I cannot only send strings but also other data as well. I will post this as a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an object containing the string as a property and pass the pointer to the object as `Integer` `LParam`. Then, in the message handler, use the string and free the object. In this way, you could not only send strings but also other data as well.

```
unit SendingStringWithPostMessageUsingObjectMainForm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

const
  WM_STRINGMESSAGE = WM_USER;

type
  TStrMsgObject = class(TObject)
  private
    fMsg: string;
  public
    constructor Create(const aMsg: string);
    property Msg: string read fMsg;
  end;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    btnSetCaption: TButton;
    btnChangeCaption: TButton;
    procedure btnChangeCaptionClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnSetCaptionClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure WMStringMessage(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_STRINGMESSAGE;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

const
  // WM_STRINGMESSAGE Actions:
  ACTION_SETCAPTION    = 0;
  ACTION_CHANGECAPTION = 1;

constructor TStrMsgObject.Create(const aMsg: string);
begin
  inherited Create;
  fMsg := aMsg;
end;

procedure TForm2.WMStringMessage(var Msg: TMessage);
// Process WM_STRINGMESSAGE messages
var
  mo: TStrMsgObject;
begin
  mo := TStrMsgObject(Msg.LParam);
  try
    case Msg.WParam of
      ACTION_SETCAPTION:
        begin
          Caption := mo.Msg;
        end;
      ACTION_CHANGECAPTION:
        begin
          Caption := Caption + mo.Msg;
        end;
    end
  finally
    mo.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.btnSetCaptionClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  System.Classes.TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      PostMessage(Handle, WM_STRINGMESSAGE, ACTION_SETCAPTION, Integer(TStrMsgObject.Create('My new caption')));
    end).Start;
end;

procedure TForm2.btnChangeCaptionClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  System.Classes.TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      PostMessage(Handle, WM_STRINGMESSAGE, ACTION_CHANGECAPTION, Integer(TStrMsgObject.Create(' changed')));
    end).Start;
end;

end.
```

Comment: What if the message is not processed, or `PostMessage` fails? You leak that object? P.S. do not post messages to the main form. Its handle can change when the window is recreated. Dedicate a hidden window for it (`AllocateHWnd`). And use casting to `LPARAM`, or `WPARAM` (not `Integer`). Finally, record would suffice.